# How to convert number to BN with web3

Tags: web3js, bignumber, frontend

I am trying to get the balance of eth from Metamask account, but I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "0.322778986" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported.
```

This is the code for retrieving the eth value :

```
  Balance: {this.props.ethBalance ? window.web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.ethBalance.toString(), 'ether') : ''}
```

How can I convert it to BN in order to display the value?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web3.eth.getBalance()` returns a `Promise` which resolves to a `string` for balance of given address in wei.

If you want to get the balance in wei, the following code should work.

```
const ethBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account);
```

If you want to display the balance in ether, you should convert wei to ether using a big number library. Luckily web3 has a function for this purpose.

```
const balanceInWei = await web3.eth.getBalance(this.state.account);
const ethBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(balanceInWei, "ether");
```

Since `web3.utils.fromWei(number [, unit])` returns a `string` if given `number` parameter is `String` or `Number`, you don't need to convert to big number to display it.

When displaying the balance in ethers, you don't need to call `web3.utils.fromWei(number [, unit])` again. Following code should display the balance in ethers.

```
Balance: {{ this.props.ethBalance || "" }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I still get the same error as before saying that it is an invalid number value.

Comment: This is probably because 'somehow' ```web3.eth.getBalance()``` returns the balance in ether. Also BN.js (which web3 uses internally) does not support for decimal numbers. Is it still gives error without converting to BN?

Comment: Ok, I spoke too soon. Apparently it took some time for the browser console to refresh, therefore I thought the error was gone. I still get the error with or without converting it.

Comment: The code I posted works correctly in my computer. Is there any chance this error happens somewhere else in your code? I mean, there should be another place where you try to convert ```"0.322778986"``` to BN.

Comment: You are right. I edited the post with the right line. I also tried `Balance: {this.props.ethBalance ? window.web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.ethBalance, 'ether') : ''}` but it sais it has to be a string or a BN for the conversion to work.

Comment: Probably ```this.props.ethBalance``` is already converted to ether (```"0.322778986"```). When displaying it, you don't need to use ```web3.utils.fromWei()``` again. Try this code ```Balance: {this.props.ethBalance || ""}```

Comment: Awesome! You're right. Now the error is gone. Please write this as an answer and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I've edited the answer according to changes made in question.